# put and delete data error err_spdy_protocol_error

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, fetch, slim

I am trying to put and delete data from a web service via fetch, but I am getting the following error

net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR

```
const Headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Request-Method': '*'};
```

const url = 'https://tesisweb.000webhostapp.com/genTesis/api/public/coo/1';

```
const req = new Request(serverUrl + url, {method: 'PUT', headers: Headers, body: obj});

return fetch(req)
    .then(status)
    .then((response) => {

        return response.json();

    });
```

In the BackEnd i using php slim and eloquent

Middelware

```
    $corsOptions = array(
"origin" => "*",
"exposeHeaders" => array("Content-Type", "X-Requested-With", "X-authentication", "X-client"),
"allowMethods" => array('GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS')
```

);
$cors = new \CorsSlim\CorsSlim($corsOptions);

$app->add($cors);

Comment: Does it work if you use `curl` or Postman?

Comment: No, but the problem is only in the hosting